# Handlebars helper to retrieve the basename of the file in which it is used

Tags: node.js, templates, handlebars.js, helper

I'm looking for a way to create a helper that simply renders the basename of the file in which the template was placed, and without requiring any additional parameters, like so: `{{ basename }}`.

In other words, if I used this helper inside two partials, say `header.hbs` and `navbar.hbs`, I would expect the name of each partial to be render in the output wherever they were used.

I've looked for hours and can't find any answers to this. Any direction or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt Handlebars will even know the file name (if there is even a file name to know) when your helper is run. You might need to hack the core Handlebars code and said hack might be bigger than you'd like.

Comment: That's what I suspected after fiddling around for a while, but I was hoping there was some hidden super-feature I was unaware of... To this: "if there is even a file name to know", I was trying to think of a way of "making" this known to handlebars with node path/fs. doesn't seem possible

Comment: The problem (probably) is that the two ways to get something into Handlebars are `Handlebars.compile` and `Handlebars.registerPartial`, neither of those know anything about files, they just know about strings. I can't guarantee that there is no magic shortcut but it seems unlikely.

Comment: This may or may not make a difference, but I'm using Grunt.js and assemble (http://github.com/assemble/assemble). Thanks for the insight though @mu is too short, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Without knowing much about your setup here is an approach.**

You need to register a helper inside your render function.  You will then call render instead of compile.  Note the below is for the backend, but you can easily adapt it to your environment.

*Handlebars has no notion of your environment so you need to set it globally somewhere.*

```
exports.render = function (name, req, context) {
    if (isBrowser()) {
        throw new Error('Render cannot be called client-side.');
    }
    handlebars.registerHelper('basename', function() {
        var host = globalBasenameSetFromEnvironment;
        return  host;
    });
    if (!handlebars.templates[name]) {
        throw new Error('Template Not Found: ' + name);
    }
    return handlebars.templates[name](context);
};
```

Comment: @Hatchare I think jonschlinkert is referring to using the node path.basename('header.hbs') to get something like 'header' to use within his file. Am I correct to assume that you're thinking of something like a url host name or a base path for other files?

I think your render function may be useful to just return the name passed (which should be the partial name, right?).

Comment: So he could do something like `var host = name;` to pass the variable in, get rid of the .hbs of course, and change the host variable to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that needs to be exposed on the context when rendering a file.

For example, assuming we have a template at the file path "some/template.hbs", which has something like the following in

```
Basename is: "{{basename}}"
```

We can render it like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var hbs = require('handlebars');

var filepath = 'some/template.hbs';
var tmpl = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');

var fn = hbs.compile(tmpl);
var str = fn({
  path: filepath,
  basename: path.basename(filepath)
});
console.log(str);
// Basename is: "template.hbs"
```